# How to force Auth0 user to login with password always?

Tags: auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

How to force the Auth0 user to always enter his password to log in with Auth0 instead of using "Last time you logged in with " button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Auth0 Lock Widget, then there is a [rememberLastLogin](https://github.com/auth0/lock#showoptions) option that should suppress the "Last time you logged in with" button.

From the docs:

> rememberLastLogin {Boolean}: Determines whether or not to show a
>   screen that allows you to quickly log in with the account you used the
>   last time when the initialScreen option is set to to "login" (the
>   default). Defaults to true.

Comment: Thanks! Hey do you know how to set the option with Auth0 Hosted Login?

Comment: Hey. The lock widget should behave similarly whether using embedded login or via auth0 hosted login page.